# TTS tool for commercial use

Tags: text-to-speech

Could you, guys, help me with searching some good TTS (Text-To-Speech) tool for commercial purposes? I checked several tool, but some of them was too expensive ($5000+), such as AT&T, other - low-quality, such as FreeTTS. I need free or low-price (up to $500) application or web service to create *wav* or *mp3* files of English words and phrase in quality suitable for education purposes.

Thanks!

P.S. Large library of ready wav or mp3 files will be also OK.

Comment: "Good" wants to cost money. That said, one can interface with Google Translate's TTS which works for up to ~100 chars.

Comment: Check out **free tts**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems, I have found service suitable for my purposes - [Acapela Box](http://www.acapela-box.com). It's priced based on the number of recorded characters and allows to download voice files in good quality and use them for commercial purposes (except on Radio or TV),

Answer (score 2):

You can use festival http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/
The online demo is not for commercial use, but offline version is. You can download compiled version for windows for example from here: http://e-guidedog.sourceforge.net/download.php
To generate a wav file with this compiled version you use it like this:
-unpack festival to C:\ (this version will not work properly if you unpack it somewhere else)
-run C:\festival\src\main\festival.exe
-in console window write this festival command: (utt.save.wave (SayText "This is a test.") "testfile.wav")
You should hear festival saying "this is a test" and your wav file should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out [yakitome](http://www.yakitome.com). This is free, has decent voices and you can create/download the files as .wav or mp3. The directions for downloading is under the FAQ's. Hope you didn't waste any money yet!

Comment: Just an FYI, Yakitome is not free for commercial use. I received a notification from them this morning on some tutorials we did for a free app, but from our for profit company. Working through with them now trying to find out how to clear this up or if we will have to find another option for recording.

Answer (score 0):

I found not bad service [iSpeech](https://www.ispeech.org/developers). It has also good pronunciation and it's free for mobile developing.

P.S By the way it's also include ASR